# How to add a new tag(GenericRelation field),when creating a new tagged-object through django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my situation: I want to build a QA system,with tagged question model.

My model code is:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-create_time']

    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('标题'),
        max_length=50
    )  
     content = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('内容'),
        max_length=2000
    )  
    tag = generic.GenericRelation(Tag)


class Tag(models.Model):    
    name = models.SlugField(_('tag'),max_length=10)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My serializer is :

```
class QuestionCreateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tag = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='name')
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('title','content','tag')
```

My views is :

```
class QuestionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionCreateSerializer
```

Then what I got is something standard output of django-rest-framework,when I access to my api ("/..../api/questions/")

When I want to post a new question, I can only choose a tag that already exists.

What I want is the clients can post a new question with a list of tags whatever they like. And if the posted tag item is a existed one then add it to the question,if not, create a new tag to attach to the question.

So, what logic can I add to the model, the serializer, or the view?

Comment: A ManyToMany field don't solve? Or tags has type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I've done it before was to create a post view for my tags, just using a view that inherits from the APIView. The data that needs to be sent is the question id, and a string of words separated by commas.  I retrieve the question object, then I call the python split on the word, then iterate either getting or creating a new tag for each token. Then I add the question to each tag in the for loop. 
Something similar to this

```
class TagAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        tags = request.DATA.get(u'tags', None)
        question = request.DATA.get(u'question', None)
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=question)
        tags = tags.split(',')
        for tag in tags:
            tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name='tag')
            tag.question_set.add(question)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_created)
```

This isn't exactly how  you do it, but this is very similar of how I've done it in the past.